# What are the specific qualities of Lord Shiva's trishul?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, shiva-purana, weapon

Does any epic or purana describes about Lord Shiva's trishul briefly? Specially Shiva Purana & Mahabharata, if I'm not wrong, Upamanyu had described something about Shiva's trishul to Lord Krishna in Mahabharata. Please describe anything mainly from these two holy books.

Answer (score 1):

Shiva’s trishul represents the three fundamental aspects of life. These are the three fundamental dimensions of life that are symbolized in many ways. They can also be called Ida, Pingala and Sushumna. These are the three basic nadis – the left, the right and the central – in the pranamaya kosha, or the energy body of the human system. Nadis are pathways or channels of prana in the system. There are 72,000 nadis that spring from the three fundamental ones.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trishula) we will find some info of shiv trishul

Comment: You need to cite some sources (preferably from scriptures) for your claims. :)

Comment: Yes I have referred many sites and then came to this answer. :)

Comment: Here we need cite scriptural sources (preferably scriptural but some other sources too allowed) for answers. Unsourced answers will be downvoted and may be deleted too. Since you are a new user you might not be aware of this rule. See the other answer. There the answerer is quoting from Shiva Purana.You have to do the same. You can use sites for reference too but you have to give link to them.

Comment: ohh ok I got that I'll edit my answer in while .:) thankx @Rickross

Answer (score 1):

In [Shiva Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226546.html), the power of Trishula was briefly described by Upamanyu.

> 18. While performing penance, ***I saw at the side of Rudra*** the imperishable highly secret weapon ***which had no other missile superior***
>       or equal to it.
> 19. It was the ***weapon Vijaya***, the **trident of the fierce weapon that destroyed all other weapons and missiles**.
> 20. There is no doubt that it could pierce through the entire earth, dry up the big ocean and cause all the luminary bodies to fall.
> 21. It was the weapon with which ***Yauvanāśva the emperor*** of great refulgence and ***Māndhātṛ*** the powerful king who conquered the three
>       worlds ***were killed*** formerly.
> 22. The arrogant Haihaya king was killed with it. When the ***demon Lavaṇa challenged king Śatrughna*** this missile was hurled at him.
> 23. When that demon was killed this ***trident had returned*** to Rudra. It had a sharp point and was highly terrifying.

Comment: From which samhita of Shiva Purana, does this information was taken? @srimannarayana k v

Comment: @aniketkumarsingh: Section 5 - Umā-Saṃhitā